# Large size image uploading issue with latest iOS dropbox sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I am trying to upload 4 to 5 mb size image on dropbox using latest iOS dropbox sdk. But every time I get **Error code =-1001 The operation couldn't be completed**.
My internet connection speed is fair enough (2 mbps).

I have also tried by reducing image size to 512kb and it gets uploaded. But if I try to upload 5 or 6 images in sequence than again i get same error after successful upload of 2 or 3 images.

I have tried using below methods.

```
[self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath]

[self.restClient uploadFileChunk:nil offset:0 fromPath:localPath]
```

Comment: you are uploading large image so you should divide the images in small chunks. you can refer this link for that:https://github.com/HarshDuggal/HDMultipartUpload

Comment: @PiyushPatel .. Thanks for reply. As i have to upload image on dropbox . Dropbox api provide to upload file in chunk. But it's also not working. I think your reference link is not for dropbox uploading.

Comment: yes you are right but here [self.restClient uploadFileChunk:nil offset:0 fromPath:localPath] your passing uploadFileChunk:nil here so i have suggested to upload it as a chunk file.

Comment: @PiyushPatel .. This is not the way you are talking about to pass chunk file in dropbox api methods. It seems you are not familiar with dropbox api methods. please check it once if possible

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes) a -1001 error means `NSURLErrorTimedOut`, meaning that the connection took too long. There are a number of factors that can contribute to this, including the device, the device's network stack and Internet connection, the particular route between your ISP and the destination servers, etc.

When it comes to your Internet connection, you only upload as fast as your Internet service provider (ISP) allows. Consumer ISP's normally provide less upload speed compared to download speed. In addition to this, your speeds may be slower than what your ISP rates it. Sometimes resetting or retrying your connection gets you a different route and better speeds, but that is outside of our control. Some ISPs also throttle sustained connections so if you see an initial high connection speed followed by lower speeds, that could be the reason.

When using `uploadFile`, you're attempting to upload the entirety of the file in one HTTPS request. If the file is big enough, along with the above considerations, this may make the request take too long and fail. For that reason, chunked uploading can be better.

When using `uploadFileChunk`, you're only attempting to upload a portion of the file per HTTPS request, meaning each request doesn't need to take as long and is less likely to fail.

In either case, one more thing to be aware of is how many simultaneous requests you're attempting to make. If you have too many running at the same time, they may all slow down, causing these failures. That being the case, you'll want to limit how many you run concurrently. Some developers choose a limit of 4 simultaneous connections, but the right number for your app will depend on the specifics of the scenario, so you may want to try a few different numbers.

Edit, here's some basic sample code for using chunked uploading:

```
- (void) doTest {

    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        NSLog(@"Running test...");

        // Write a file to the local documents directory
        NSString *text = @"Hello world. Usually something much longer here.";
        NSString *filename = @"working-draft.txt";
        NSString *localDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
        self.localPath = [localDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        [text writeToFile:self.localPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        self.dbClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        self.dbClient.delegate = self;

        // Start the upload. No upload ID known yet
        [self.dbClient uploadFileChunk:nil offset:0 fromPath:self.localPath];

    }


}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFileChunk:(NSString *)uploadId newOffset:(unsigned long long)offset
          fromFile:(NSString *)localPath expires:(NSDate *)expiresDate {

    NSLog(@"uploadedFileChunk: %@, newOffset: %llu, fromFile: %@, expires: %@", uploadId, offset, localPath, expiresDate);

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDictionary *attrs = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:self.localPath error: NULL];

    // in real use, there's probably a dangerous race condition here in checking the size each time, but this is just for demonstration purposes
    if (offset >= [attrs fileSize]) {
        // all data has been uploaded
        NSLog(@"Finishing upload...");
        [self.dbClient uploadFile:@"chunked_uploaded_file.txt" toPath:@"/" withParentRev:nil fromUploadId:uploadId];
    } else {
        // more data to upload
        NSLog(@"Continuing upload...");
        [self.dbClient uploadFileChunk:uploadId offset:offset fromPath:localPath];
    }

}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadFileChunkFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"uploadFileChunkFailedWithError: %@", error);
    // in real use, the app should probably implement some retrying logic here

}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadFileChunkProgress:(CGFloat)progress {

    NSLog(@"uploadFileChunkProgress: %f", progress);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. But I do uploading using single request at a time. But it does not make any difference with direct uploading and uploading with chunk data. I get the same error in both. Do you have any sample code for Dropbox api which work with large size image uploading using chunk data? that will be very helpful to us.

Comment: I added some sample code to my post. Hope it helps!